# flatiron.js: how to turn of cache for static files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flatiron.js

I'm using the flatiron static plugins like this:

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.static, {
    dir: './app/assets',
    cache: false
});
```

The st module has caching options, like cache: false. But it doesn't work like that. I don't know if the flatiron plugin doesn't accept the cache option. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to plug in the plugin like this:

```
app.use(flatiron.plugins.static, {dir: './app/assets', url: '/assets'});
```

Otherwise all root (/) routes would have been cached and served static.